# Can we increase the navigation's contrast on Meta.SE?

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, usability, header

The navigation's contrast is too low, which hampers my ability to quickly scan the navigation. I find myself many times having to concentrate and read the section I'm in. I think part of the problem is that the community logos bleed underneath the main navigation. Also the navigation text is about the same height as the community logos.

When a link is "selected/active", text state though turns a light blue that, in my opinion, is really close to the header background color. It becomes hard to read, especially links such as "Questions" and "Tags".

I vote to insert some sort of color background on selected/active links to help push it forward from the background.

[image: Header as of Dec 22, 2014]